# read an ics file using iCal.Net and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, package-management

I am trying to read an .ics file using powershell and the iCal.Net package.

```
# Install-Package NodaTime -Force -MaximumVersion 3.0.0
# Install-Package iCal.Net -Force

# load assemblies
Write-Host loading assemblies -ForegroundColor Green
Add-Type -LiteralPath 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\NodaTime.3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\NodaTime.dll'
Add-Type -LiteralPath 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Ical.Net.4.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Ical.Net.dll'

# define ics url
Write-Host defining ics url -ForegroundColor Green
$icsurl = 'https://url_to/basic.ics'

# load ics
Write-Host invoking web request -ForegroundColor Green
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $icsurl

# deserialize ICS
Write-Host deserializing ics -ForegroundColor Green
$calendar = [Ical.Net.Calendar]::Load( $response.Content )

Write-Host $calendar
```

Even though I can see the .ics file contains multiple events, the $calendar variable doesn't return any results.

This is the output of the script

```
loading assemblies
defining ics url
invoking web request
deserializing ics
Ical.Net.Calendar
```

And $response.Content simply shows me the contents of the .ics file

Comment: Is calendar and property or a method?  Error says "Method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this example](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki/Deserialize-an-ics-file) it looks like you have to use the *static* method [`Calendar.Load()`](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/1ad17e51a0e71b30aabf88d95c16066f4db6e08b/src/Ical.Net/Calendar.cs#L17). It accepts a string, so you don't need to download to a file. You can do everything in memory.

A [static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods?view=powershell-7.3) is called without an object, instead you call it using `::` on a *class*.

```sh
# download ICS
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $icsurl

# TODO: handle download errors

# deserialize ICS
$calendar = [Ical.Net.Calendar]::Load( $response.Content )
```

To discover static members you can use this command:

```sh
[Ical.Net.Calendar] | Get-Member -Static
```

Comment: on the "deserialize ICS" command I get an error: Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'NodaTime, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4226afe0d9b296d1' or one of its dependencies. The        
system cannot find the file specified." Even though I've loaded the NodaTime dlls.

Comment: @aristosv Try this: `Install-Package NodaTime -Force -MaximumVersion 3.0.0`

Comment: @aristosv Similarly, in the `Add-Type` line use `Get-Package NodaTime -MaximumVersion 3.0.0`

Comment: I've updated the question to show exactly the dll's I'm loading, but there is no output, even though I can see that the .ics file contains multiple events.

Comment: it's ok, I used ($calendar).Events and I got the output. Thank you. Answer accepted.